# Remove rest of string after the second to last index of

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lastindexof

I'm relatively new to JS and pretty confused. I have a URL string: https://a/b/c/d/e/f. These are all dynamic characters and change often (could be https://x/s/g/e/h/d for example) In some cases I want to remove only f, in which I use LastIndexOf. In other cases I want to remove both the last and second to last EG: e/f. How can this be done successfully? I tried using a split but this just replaced the '/' with ',' for some reason.

working f example

```
var url = https://a/b/c/d/e/f
var new = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') +1);
```

current split e/f example

```
var new = url.split('/')
console.log(new[new.length -2]);
```

This prints as: https:,,a,b,c,d,e,f,

Comment: split just splits the string into an array of strings and not replace it

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `new` as a variable name

Comment: @Pete thanks, that was just a quick name used for the purpose of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are

```
const str = 'https://a/b/c/d/e/f'

function removeSegments(url, times) {
    const segments = url.split('/')
    return segments.slice(0, segments.length - times).join('/')
}

console.log(removeSegments(str, 1)) // 'https://a/b/c/d/e'
console.log(removeSegments(str, 2)) // 'https://a/b/c/d'
```

Comment: This was the easiest and cleanest way for me to replicate this into my code, thank you

Comment: Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option, using regex replacement.  To remove the final path only:

```
url = "https://a/b/c/d/e/f";
url = url.replace(/\/[^/]+$/mg, "");
```

To remove the final *two* paths:

```
url = "https://a/b/c/d/e/f";
url = url.replace(/\/[^/]+\/[^/]+$/mg, "");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, when I add the reg ex in, on replace(/**\** it gives an error reading: unterminated Regular expression literal.

Comment: @Uciebila Your comment makes no sense, and I can only comment that my answer solved your problem in fewer lines of code than the answer you accepted.

Comment: From some research I found thatbecause my code is within a react app, it is a .js and not a .jsx. Which meant that using the above code threw an error that wouldnt be fixed until I changed my file extension, which would break the react app. With the way I added the accepted answer into my code it only needed two lines

Comment: Strange.  It is too bad that your framework is limiting what you can and cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

You need to split the pathname by `/` and then use `Array#slice` to take only the parts you want. Then join those again by `/`.

Here is an example:

```js
var url = new URL('https://a/b/c/d/e/f');

console.log(
  url.origin +
  url.pathname.split('/').slice(0, -2).join('/')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

split() creates an array of substrings that is passed in the split function.
So when you write

url.split('/') it will create an array of substrings with / as delimeter.

The answer could be :

get the index of the element till when you want to remove your string by using :

```
var index = indexOf(x)
```

then pass it in the function.

```
var str1 = str.substr(0, index)
```

str1 will be your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var num;
for ( var i=0; i< num; i++) {
    url= url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
}
```